# Extended Choice Parameter Plugin Use

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I was wondering if anyone would be willing to provide a little help on the Extended Choice Parameter plugin for Jenkins.

Currently I have an Application Choice Parameter which has a list like so:

```
all
payroll
parts
service
business office
general ledger
PD2500R
GL1000D
GL1100R
GL0406R
SD1700R
PD0720R
SD1140R
```

What I would like to do is have the ability to be able to have a list like so:

```
all
business office
   BO object
   BO object
   BO object
general ledger
    GL1000D
    GL1100R
    GL0406R
```

Then if the user for example chooses just Business office it runs everything under Business Office, or if they just choose one of the objects under Business Office it just runs the tests for that one object.

Is the Extended Choice Parameter plugin the right option for this, and if so, how would I go about setting it up. I downloaded that plugin, but there is not a whole lot of documentation on how to actually use it.